Cannot add image (png, jpeg, etc.) but can add pdf, 403 forbidden when posting
I just encountered a bug when I am trying to post with images. When I am adding media using "Add Media" button, the image will not add and will have this error:


POST https://philsa.gov.ph/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 403 (Forbidden)

However, when I am trying to add other media such as pdf, it will add.

When I tried using an inline html image syntax to add the image. When saving the draft or publishing it, it will return a 403 forbidden page.
We did not change anything from .htaccess, but just started experiencing it. What I have done so far:

Updating securit plugins.
Changing the uploads permission to 755.

But no avail on these steps.
Wordpress version: WordPress 6.3.4

Are you using any cache plugins? Try purging the cache then checked for the permissions applied to cached files.

I only have WP Server Stats, I have purge the cache in that plugin. The issue still persists. I cant even add older files before the issue arose.

Many times, this type of issue occurs due to SSL as well. So, try adding these plugins one by one, such as Really Simple SSL, SSL Insecure Content Fixer, or WP Force SSL & HTTPS SSL Redirect, and see if the issue is fixed
